# Filterable StickyListHeadersAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours, the idea is to have a filterable list helped by an EditText. For this I use a StickyListHeadersListView with a filterable StickyListHeadersAdapter. Here is my current code:

```
public class PersonaFilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter, Filterable {

private int mResource;
private List<User> mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
private Set<User> mUserHashSet;

/** Filter parameters **/
private ArrayList<User> mFilteredObjects = new ArrayList<>();
private Filter mFilter;

public PersonaFilterAdapter(int resource, List<User> objects, Set<User> userHashSet) {
    this.mResource = resource;
    this.mUserList.addAll(objects);
    this.mFilteredObjects.addAll(objects);
    this.mUserHashSet = userHashSet;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.avatar = (SimpleDraweeView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userAvatar);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        holder.position = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userPosition);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    User user = getItem(position);

    int size = 100;
    String imgString = SlingCloudinary.getInstance().getAvatar(user, size, size);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imgString);
    holder.avatar.setImageURI(uri);
    holder.name.setText(String.format("%s %s", user.getName(), user.getLastname()));
    holder.position.setText(user.getDescription());

    if (mUserHashSet != null) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
        if (mUserHashSet.contains(user)) {
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        } else {
            listView.setItemChecked(position, false);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}

public void updateUsersList(List<User> userList) {
    mUserList.clear();
    mUserList.addAll(userList);
    mFilteredObjects.clear();
    mFilteredObjects.addAll(mUserList);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void notifyFilterDataSetChanged(List<User> userList) {
    mFilteredObjects.clear();
    mFilteredObjects.addAll(userList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public User getItem(int position) {
    return mFilteredObjects.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFilteredObjects.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new AppFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

class ViewHolder {
    SimpleDraweeView avatar;
    TextView name;
    TextView position;
}

class HeaderViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}

@Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HeaderViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_section_persona, parent, false);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personaSectionText);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // set header text as first char in name
    CharSequence headerChar = getItem(position).getName().subSequence(0, 1);
    holder.text.setText(headerChar);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public long getHeaderId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getName().subSequence(0,1).charAt(0);
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

private class AppFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence chars) {
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (chars != null && chars.length() > 0) {
            String mask = chars.toString();
            ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (User user : mUserList) {
                if (keepObject(user, mask)) {
                    userList.add(user);
                }
            }
            result.count = userList.size();
            result.values = userList;
        } else {
            // add all objects
            result.values = mUserList;
            result.count = mUserList.size();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results.count > 0) {
            notifyFilterDataSetChanged((List<User>) results.values);
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}

private boolean keepObject(User user, String mask) {
    mask = mask.toLowerCase();
    return user.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(mask);
}
}
```

Now everything is displayed well at first I call the *updateUsersList* list function which calls *notifyDataSetChanged* and it works fine, I can see all the list with sections.

Afterwards when using the EditText, by typing the letter **B** for instance the *Filter* class returns me 2 filtered items, I then pass this list of 2 items to the *notifyFilterDataSetChanged* function so that sticky list only displays 2 items. And at this point it fails, the whole list remains the same. I am probably missing at this point, I've been reading all good recommendations but in vain. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you've got a wrong getItemId implementation. If you use hasStableIds(true) you shouldn't rely on position. Try to make it something like

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getId();
}
```

I suppose you've got some sort of id in your User class, haven't you?

Second, do you invoke publishResults in UI thread? Try to make it runOnUiThread() or listView.post() to check if everything is right.

Third, do you have several adapter initialization? Check if you pass the event to the right one (the one that is binded to listview).

Comment: That's a good point you mentioned I used this hasStableIds without knowing what it does. Even though this still doesn't work when setting to false. I also tried runOnUIThread and listView.post(), still not lucky..

Comment: Other than that you implementation seems pretty normal to me. Let me clarify it - even though your filtered implementation returns the correct result (provide filtered list with correct size etc) and notify the adapter through notifyFilterDataSetChanged, the list displays only the initial values (not filtered list)? May be you got several adapter initialization and pass the events to the wrong one? Can you check the adapter size before and after passing OnTextChanged events, but check it directly like listView.getAdapter().getCount() ?

Comment: And return the hasStableIds to true, just implement normal logic to getItemId()

Comment: You're damn right it was several instances! I forgot two mention I was using a SlidingTabLayout in one part of my app. First tab was using this adapter, and knowing that I had a second tab soon to be implemented, I made the mistake of implementing this adapter in the second tab as a placeholder (stupid me!!). Thanks